# How to Change Tempo of a Notes Sequence in Magenta?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, midi, magenta

I tried changing qpm. But it doesn't change anything.
I want to change the tempo of the notes sequence.
I am working on Colab, my notebook can be found [here](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/magenta/hello_magenta/hello_magenta.ipynb).

```
    from note_seq.protobuf import music_pb2
    from note_seq import sequences_lib
    
    twinkle_twinkle = music_pb2.NoteSequence()
    
    # Add the notes to the sequence.
    twinkle_twinkle.notes.add(pitch=60, start_time=0.0, end_time=0.5, velocity=80)
    twinkle_twinkle.notes.add(pitch=60, start_time=0.5, end_time=1.0, velocity=80)
    twinkle_twinkle.notes.add(pitch=67, start_time=1.0, end_time=1.5, velocity=80)
    twinkle_twinkle.notes.add(pitch=67, start_time=1.5, end_time=2.0, velocity=80)
    twinkle_twinkle.notes.add(pitch=69, start_time=2.0, end_time=2.5, velocity=80)
    twinkle_twinkle.notes.add(pitch=69, start_time=2.5, end_time=3.0, velocity=80)
    twinkle_twinkle.notes.add(pitch=67, start_time=3.0, end_time=4.0, velocity=80)
    twinkle_twinkle.notes.add(pitch=65, start_time=4.0, end_time=4.5, velocity=80)
    twinkle_twinkle.notes.add(pitch=65, start_time=4.5, end_time=5.0, velocity=80)
    twinkle_twinkle.notes.add(pitch=64, start_time=5.0, end_time=5.5, velocity=80)
    twinkle_twinkle.notes.add(pitch=64, start_time=5.5, end_time=6.0, velocity=80)
    twinkle_twinkle.notes.add(pitch=62, start_time=6.0, end_time=6.5, velocity=80)
    twinkle_twinkle.notes.add(pitch=62, start_time=6.5, end_time=7.0, velocity=80)
    twinkle_twinkle.notes.add(pitch=60, start_time=7.0, end_time=8.0, velocity=80) 
    twinkle_twinkle.total_time = 8
    
    twinkle_twinkle.tempos.add(qpm=120);
    
    
    # This is a colab utility method that visualizes a NoteSequence.
    note_seq.plot_sequence(twinkle_twinkle)
    
    # This is a colab utility method that plays a NoteSequence.
    note_seq.play_sequence(twinkle_twinkle,synth=note_seq.fluidsynth)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find several examples at magenta/demos in github. You can find there this solution. Hope it helps:

```
from note_seq.protobuf import music_pb2
import copy

def change_tempo(note_sequence, new_tempo):
    new_sequence = copy.deepcopy(note_sequence)
    ratio = note_sequence.tempos[0].qpm / new_tempo
    for note in new_sequence.notes:
        note.start_time = note.start_time * ratio
        note.end_time = note.end_time * ratio
    new_sequence.tempos[0].qpm = new_tempo
    return new_sequence

twinkle_twinkle = music_pb2.NoteSequence()

# Add the notes to the sequence.
twinkle_twinkle.notes.add(pitch=60, start_time=0.0, end_time=0.5, velocity=80)
twinkle_twinkle.notes.add(pitch=60, start_time=0.5, end_time=1.0, velocity=80)
twinkle_twinkle.notes.add(pitch=67, start_time=1.0, end_time=1.5, velocity=80)
twinkle_twinkle.notes.add(pitch=67, start_time=1.5, end_time=2.0, velocity=80)
twinkle_twinkle.notes.add(pitch=69, start_time=2.0, end_time=2.5, velocity=80)
twinkle_twinkle.notes.add(pitch=69, start_time=2.5, end_time=3.0, velocity=80)
twinkle_twinkle.notes.add(pitch=67, start_time=3.0, end_time=4.0, velocity=80)
twinkle_twinkle.notes.add(pitch=65, start_time=4.0, end_time=4.5, velocity=80)
twinkle_twinkle.notes.add(pitch=65, start_time=4.5, end_time=5.0, velocity=80)
twinkle_twinkle.notes.add(pitch=64, start_time=5.0, end_time=5.5, velocity=80)
twinkle_twinkle.notes.add(pitch=64, start_time=5.5, end_time=6.0, velocity=80)
twinkle_twinkle.notes.add(pitch=62, start_time=6.0, end_time=6.5, velocity=80)
twinkle_twinkle.notes.add(pitch=62, start_time=6.5, end_time=7.0, velocity=80)
twinkle_twinkle.notes.add(pitch=60, start_time=7.0, end_time=8.0, velocity=80) 
twinkle_twinkle.total_time = 8

twinkle_twinkle.tempos.add(qpm=60);

# New note sequence with changed tempo
twinkle_twinkle_tempo_changed = change_tempo(twinkle_twinkle, new_tempo = 130)

# This is a colab utility method that visualizes a NoteSequence.
note_seq.plot_sequence(twinkle_twinkle)

# This is a colab utility method that plays a NoteSequence.
note_seq.play_sequence(twinkle_twinkle,synth=note_seq.fluidsynth)
note_seq.play_sequence(twinkle_twinkle_tempo_changed,synth=note_seq.fluidsynth)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [stretch_sequence_note()](https://github.com/magenta/note-seq/blob/master/note_seq/sequences_lib.py#L1295):

> ```
> Apply a constant temporal stretch to a NoteSequence proto.
>   Args:
>     note_sequence: The NoteSequence to stretch.
>     stretch_factor: How much to stretch the NoteSequence. Values greater than
>       one increase the length of the NoteSequence (making it "slower"). Values
>       less than one decrease the length of the NoteSequence (making it
>       "faster").
>     in_place: If True, the input note_sequence is edited directly.
>   Returns:
>     A stretched copy of the original NoteSequence.
> ```

To make it 2x faster you can use a `stretch_factor` of `0.5` like this:

```python
from note_seq.sequences_lib import stretch_note_sequence

faster_twinkle_twinkle = stretch_note_sequence(twinkle_twinkle, 0.5)
```